# Not able to connect Cassandra from my sbt project

Tags: scala, cassandra, sbt

My code is working while i worked in eclipse and added **cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar** in referenced library.Now i make and sbt project and added following dependency in **build.sbt**

`libraryDependencies +="com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.2"`
But while i am calling the class where i use datastax library it is producing ERROR like

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I don't know why it is not able to find Cluster class.
As it is some configuration issue so i dont posted my code snippet but 
If required i can post that also.

Comment: Is this happening during the test or integration test part of the build, if so you need to put it into the test scope.

com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.2 % "it, test"

Comment: @AlIacovella can you give me exact syntax which i have to put in build.sbt

Comment: try adding the  "it, test" at the end of your dependency as you see above.